# How to overwrite array inside h5 file using h5py

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, h5py

I'm trying to overwrite a numpy array that's a small part of a pretty complicated h5 file.

I'm extracting an array, changing some values, then want to re-insert the array into the h5 file.

I have no problem extracting the array that's nested.

```
f1 = h5py.File(file_name,'r')
X1 = f1['meas/frame1/data'].value
f1.close()
```

My attempted code looks something like this with no success:

```
f1 = h5py.File(file_name,'r+')
dset = f1.create_dataset('meas/frame1/data', data=X1)
f1.close()
```

As a sanity check, I executed this in Matlab using the following code, and it worked with no problems.

```
h5write(file1, '/meas/frame1/data', X1);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this successfully?

Answer (score 54):

You want to assign values, not create a dataset:

```py
f1 = h5py.File(file_name, 'r+')     # open the file
data = f1['meas/frame1/data']       # load the data
data[...] = X1                      # assign new values to data
f1.close()                          # close the file
```

To confirm the changes were properly made and saved:

```py
f1 = h5py.File(file_name, 'r')
np.allclose(f1['meas/frame1/data'].value, X1)
#True
```

Comment: That `data[...] = X1` is critical! Don't make the mistake of doing `data = X1`.

Comment: The second block is only to check whether everything is closed, right? So the first 4 lines do the actual job.

Comment: Another tripwire is that you have to overwrite the full individual data point; so if your data is e.g. 3D points you have to update the full 3D point. Changes to one element of the data point (e.g. only the Z-Coordinate) will not change anything

Comment: @Dusch, You're right that it's just a check and that the first four lines do the job, but actually it does not close anything it checks whether the values match. See [`np.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html)

Comment: Is appending [...] necessary if we are only updating part of the dataset? e.g. if we were to do data[5:] = X1, where len(data) = len(X1)+5 ?

Answer (score 44):

[askewchan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22925117/1668646) describes the way to do it (you cannot create a dataset under a name that already exists, but you can of course modify the dataset's data). Note, however, that the dataset must have the same shape as the data (`X1`) you are writing to it. If you want to *replace* the dataset with some other dataset of different shape, you first have to delete it:

```
del f1['meas/frame1/data']
dset = f1.create_dataset('meas/frame1/data', data=X1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Different scenarios:

1. Partial changes to dataset

```
with h5py.File(file_name,'r+') as ds:
  ds['meas/frame1/data'][5] = val # change index 5 to scalar "val"
  ds['meas/frame1/data'][3:7] = vals # change values of indices 3--6 to "vals"
```

2. Change each value of dataset (identical dataset sizes)

```
with h5py.File(file_name,'r+') as ds:
  ds['meas/frame1/data'][...] = X1 # change array values to those of "X1"
```

3. Overwrite dataset to one of different size

```
with h5py.File(file_name,'r+') as ds:
  del ds['meas/frame1/data'] # delete old, differently sized dataset
  ds.create_dataset('meas/frame1/data',data=X1) # implant new-shaped dataset "X1"
```

Since the File object is a context manager, using with statements is a nice way to package your code, and automatically close out of your dataset once you're done altering it. (You don't want to be in read/write mode if you only need to read off data!)