# Converting all arrays in a PyTables/HDF5 file from float64 to float32

Tags: arrays, numpy, hdf5, pytables, h5py

I have a PyTables file with a considerable amount of subdirectories. I have a way of iterating through all the array datatypes in the table. They are float64; I want to convert the file **in place** while converting all data points from float64 to float32.

[According to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922584/how-to-overwrite-array-inside-h5-file-using-h5py), one way to overwrite arrays is to assign values. I have the following code snippet which tries to take this "count" value/array in the table, converts it to float32, and assigns it back to the table:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

# filehead is a string for a file
with h5py.File(filehead, 'r+') as f:
    # Lots of stuff here ... e.g. `head` is a string

    print("/obsnorm/Standardizer/count {}".format(f[head+'/obsnorm/Standardizer/count']))
    print("count value: {}".format(f[head+'/obsnorm/Standardizer/count'].value))
    f[head+'/obsnorm/Standardizer/count'][...] = (f[head+'/obsnorm/Standardizer/count'].value).astype('float32')
    print("/obsnorm/Standardizer/count {}".format(f[head+'/obsnorm/Standardizer/count']))
    print("count value: {}".format(f[head+'/obsnorm/Standardizer/count'].value))
```

Unfortunately, the result of the printing is:

```
/obsnorm/Standardizer/count <HDF5 dataset "count": shape (), type "<f8">
count value: 512364.0
/obsnorm/Standardizer/count <HDF5 dataset "count": shape (), type "<f8">
count value: 512364.0
```

In other words, before the assignment, the type of count is f8, or float64. After casting it, the type is *still* float64.

How do I modify this in-place so that the data is truly understood as float32?

Comment: Your linked SO makes it clear that you can only overwrite the data if the shape is the same; otherwise you need to make a new dataset.  The same applies to `dtype`.  To change `dtype` you have make a new dataset, either in this file or a new one.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I suppose I was hoping that h5py had an internal method which could do this conversion. But I can figure out how to make the new dataset.

Comment: You could explore the base `HDF5` code and documentation (C++ and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by hpaulj in the comments, I decided to simply recreate a duplicate HDF5 file except making the datasets of type `f4` (same as float32) and I was able to achieve my coding goals.

The pseudocode is as follows:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

# Open the original file jointly with new file, with `float32` at the end.
with h5py.File(oldfile, 'r') as f, h5py.File(newfile[:-3]+'_float32.h5', 'w') as newf:
    # `head` is some directory structure
    # Create groups to follow the same directory structure
    newf.create_group(head)

    # When it comes time to create a dataset, make the cast here.
    newdata = (f[head+'/name_here'].value).astype('float32')
    newf.create_dataset(head+'/name_here', data=newdata, dtype='f4')

    # Proceed for all other datasets.
```