# updating a key value in hdf5 using python and h5py

Tags: python, python-3.x, hdf5, h5py

I am having a `hdf5` file with several keys. I want to update the values of all the keys after doing some adjustment. How to do that?

Here is my code:

```
hf=h5py.File(fileName,"r+")
keys=hf.keys()
for i in keys:
    df=hf[i].value
    df=df-np.mean(df)
hf.close()
```

But then when I read this file in `"r"` mode, it shows still the same mean which means it hasn't updated. Any idea where it might be going wrong?

The above issue is fixed in the answer provided. However,
I am now trying to calibrate the resultant data.
The code which I am using is:

```
data = hf[key][...]
hf[key][...] = data*calibration_factor
```

Just for the simple calibration. However, its resulting to all zeroes in hf[key][...]. Any possible solution for this? I am struggling a lot on this,thanks for understanding.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that earlier, just now saw again, yes, its almost same, but could you please guide what that [...] means cause i have to use it twice, as i have to use it multiple times.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42190783/what-does-three-dots-in-python-mean-when-indexing-what-looks-like-a-number?

Comment: Thanks, I saw that earlier, just now saw again, yes, its almost same, but could you please guide what that [...] means cause i have to use it twice, as i have to use it multiple times. as its not straight assign but df=df-np.mean(df), so how to use [...] in this case?

Comment: I have poster a complete answer with an explanation. Maybe just a comment: I think that by 'key' you actually mean 'dataset'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22925117/2646505): you want to **assign values**, not create a dataset. The latter would in this case in any case not work, as the datasets exists.

To assign values you can use Python ellipsis indexing (the `...` indexing):

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

# create some file
# ----------------

hf = h5py.File('example.hdf5', 'w')

hf['/foo'] = np.random.random(100)
hf['/bar'] = np.random.random(100) + 10.

hf.close()

# set all datasets to have a zero mean
# ------------------------------------

hf = h5py.File('example.hdf5', 'r+')

for key in hf:

  data = hf[key][...]

  hf[key][...] = data - np.mean(data)

hf.close()

# verify
# ------

hf = h5py.File('example.hdf5', 'r')

for key in hf:

  print(key, hf[key][...].shape, np.mean(hf[key][...]))

hf.close()
```

How the `...` exactly works depends on the class/library that you are using, in particular of how `__getitem__` is implemented. For h5py you can consult [the documentation](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data) which gives some insight, look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20928136/input-and-output-numpy-arrays-to-h5py), or search for other good references (that surely exist). What I can tell you in this context is that the `...` can be used to read and assign values of a dataset. This is illustrated above, where `...` has been used as an alternative to your `.value` operator.

What went wrong in your example is the you assumed that `df` was a pointer to the data. This is not the case, it is a copy. In fact `df` lives on the memory, while the data stored in the file lives on this disk. So modify `df` will not do anything to your file (as is wanted behaviour is many cases). You need to actively modify the file's content, as is being done is this answer.

*A final note: This code is very simple. For example, it works only for files without groups. If you want to be more general you would have to include some check(s).*

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked that way, I am facing another difficulty similar      data = hf[key][...]
hf[key][...] = data*calibration_factor, for the simple calculation data is to be calibrated by a factor. Unfortunately this results to all zeroes in the resultant dataset, hf[key][...]. However, if I assign it to any other variable it works fine. Any idea whats the issue?